# Can I push into an array from a set?

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

How should I go about doing this, can I even push or is there some other method I can use to add the set to my global array?

I'll just give my javascript for now if you really need the HTML and CSS, I can give it but I don't think it is needed.

Like the set does what it's supposed too, but I'm not sure if its being saved into an actual Array that I'll be able to call later on down the line or not.

I don't think the push at the end is needed, or is it doing anything at the moment.

Guess I should give more concept, I am building a calculator and trying to keep from multiple operators being shown.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39wx1edo/)

```js
'use strict';

const input = document.querySelector('#input'), // input/output button
  numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.numbers div'), // number buttons
  operators = document.querySelectorAll('.operators div'), // operator buttons
  result = document.querySelector('#result'), // equal button
  clear = document.querySelector('#clear'); // clear button


let numberInput = []
let operatorsInput = []

document.querySelectorAll('.numbers div').forEach(buttonPress => {
  buttonPress.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    numberInput.push(parseInt(event.target.textContent));
    console.log(numberInput)
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll('.operators div').forEach(buttonPress => {
  buttonPress.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    operatorsInput.push(event.target.textContent);
    // operatorsInput.from(noDuplicates);
  let noDuplicates = [...new Set(operatorsInput)];
  let operatorsND = Array.from(noDuplicates)
  console.log(operatorsND);
  operatorsInput.push(operatorsND)
  });
});
```

Comment: Why not use a `Set` from the beginning? Instead of `let operatorsInput = []`, use `let operatorsInput = new Set()` and then add items to it via `operatorsInput.add()`. It seems you only use the `Set` to ensure that the items in the `Array` are unique – a behaviour `Set` has by default. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: Why not? Because didn't know I could, and I can't seem to get it to push the "button" presses.. to the set.

Comment: Would you mind to tell what you're trying to achieve? It's not clear what you want to happen/what result you expect _from the code in the operators click handler_.

Comment: @David for sure I got it put into a jsfiddle, and I am trying to have it where you can not have multiple operators in the array.. i.e "++" or "*+-+" anything like that.. https://jsfiddle.net/39wx1edo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the solution is as simple as this (I skipped some parts of your example code):

```js
// ... elided ...

let numberInput = []
let operatorsInput = new Set(); // <-- make a Set by default

document.querySelectorAll('.numbers div').forEach(buttonPress => {
  // ... elided ...
});

document.querySelectorAll('.operators div').forEach(buttonPress => {
  buttonPress.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    operatorsInput.add(event.target.textContent); // <-- "push" to the Set
    
    console.log(...operatorsInput.values()) // <-- read & display values in the Set
  });
});
```

This ensures you have each operator only *once* inside `operatorsInput`.

Comment: Awesome yeah, I was still trying to push the button presses... instead of add, I understand now, awesome thank you. Obviously am new to coding so don't 100% understand how some of these methods work just started working with Set this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can push.

This line of code allocates memory and place all elements from the set to the newly created array.

`let noDuplicates = [...new Set(operatorsInput)];`

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's pushing to the array in the global scope tho? Whenever I console log i'm not getting any feedback.

Comment: Could you please provide an abstract example on jsfiddle or jsbin of what exactly you want to achieve. It would be easier to suggest a solution. Thanks

Comment: Added a fiddle to the main post.

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi Please don't encourage people to link to a jsfiddle/jsbin/whatsoever. Instead, encourage them to create a MCVE/MRE as described in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @David oops. Well, added a fiddle.. It seems easier than to have the whole page flooded with code.. sorry